# Failed to build page - JekyllGalleryTag

Tags: github, jekyll, liquid

I've set up a image gallery, with sunset pictures, which works fine locally, when generated with jekyll.

But I can't push a new file sunset.html because of some errors in a liquid tag 
(JekyllGalleryTag).

I can't find the reason why and google yielded no results.

My images is located at :/images/sunset

I have this in my _config.yml:

```
name: Nillers Skriblerier
markdown: redcarpet
pygments: true
url: http://nielsrasmus.github.io
description: Min egen blog
gallerytag:
   dir: images/sunset
   url: /images/sunset
   thumb_width: 150
   thumb_height: 150
   columns: 4
```

This is the sunset.html page:

```
---
layout: default
title: Solnedgange
---

<div class="posts">
<br>

<h2>Solnedgange</h2>

{% gallery solnedgange %}
cliffhouse2008.jpg:: Billedet er taget fra restauranten “Cliff house” i det vestlige San Fransisco. 2008
santacruz2008.jpg:: Solnedgang over “The Boardwalk” Santa Cruz, Californien. 2008
paros2009.jpg:: Solnedgang i Ægæerhavet. Billedet er taget på færgen på vej til Paros. 2009
skjern2012.jpg:: Solnedgang over Skjern å. 2012
lissabon2012.jpg:: Solnedgang over Lissabon. 2012
menorca2013.jpg:: Ciutadella de Menorca. Solnedgang set fra torvet. 2013
mao2013.jpg:: Solnedgang over Mao, Menorca. 2013
mao2_2013.jpg:: Solnedgang over bådehavnen i Mao, Menorca. 2013
hishult2013.jpg:: Solnedgang over Oxhultasjøn, Hishult Sverige. 2013
hishult2_2013.jpg:: Endnu en solnedgang over Oxhultasjøn, Hishult Sverige. 2013
ribe2013.jpg:: Solnedgang over søen ved campingpladsen i Ribe. 2013
{% endgallery %}

</div>
```

The funny thing is that JekyllGalleryTag is generating thumbnails in my _site directory (suppose it should?)

I keep getting this message from github:

```
The page build failed with the following error:

The tag `gallery` in `sunset.html` is not a recognized Liquid tag.
```

But it works perfectly fine locally on my machine with jekyll??

Anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jekyll on Github Pages [does not run custom plugins](https://help.github.com/articles/pages-don-t-build-unable-to-run-jekyll#unsafe-plugins). As mentioned on that FAQ, an option would be to build locally, and push the generated site to Github Pages.

JekyllGalleryTag is [a plugin](https://github.com/redwallhp/JekyllGalleryTag) which would not be run. But also you do not have it checked in. (There is no _plugins folder [currently in your repository](https://github.com/nielsrasmus/nielsrasmus.github.io/tree/1f2d4f46d1619dd9fe62331499ba4d5b15f241e7))

The images are not being generated by Jekyll running on Github Pages, but rather you have them [checked in explicitly](https://github.com/nielsrasmus/nielsrasmus.github.io/tree/1f2d4f46d1619dd9fe62331499ba4d5b15f241e7/images/sunset).

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for replying.
Yes i found out *sigh !! What to do know, what is the easiest work-around without spoiling my site? 
Are you familiar with a step-by-step guide on how to do this?

Comment: The basic principal is that you check the source into an alternate branch. You generate the site on your local machine and check the output into the master branch (published by GHPages), with the marker file to tell ghpages to serve the site as is. There are a number of blogs that go into this step by step, with slight variations depending on what makes sense to the author / specifics about their sites to work around.